# PHP html decoding help - converting: A &#039;quote&#039; is <b>bold</b>

Tags: php, html-encode

I need to convert a string like this:

```
A &#039;quote&#039; is <b>bold</b>
```

into:

```
A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

`html_entity_decode()` did not work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Make sure you use the right quote_style:

`html_entity_decode('A &#039;quote&#039; is <b>bold</b>', ENT_QUOTES);`

ENT_QUOTES Will convert both double and single quotes. ([PHP Manual: html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode))

Comment: That helps - thats exactly it - it worked fine after this! Thanks RObert!

Answer (score 25):

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
```

You can replace "UTF-8" with whatever encoding you need (though depending on the encoding you choose, certain characters may not be representable).

Comment: its not wokring in my case