# How to strip &#039; and &quote; in Highchart legend values?

Tags: highcharts

i have to strip these tags in Highchart legend values. please review the legend values:

```
data: [
{/literal}
{foreach from=$value[2] item=an key=a}
{literal}
{name: '{/literal}{$a}:{$an}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$an}{literal}, color: '#6B8E23'},
{/literal}
{/foreach}
{foreach from=$value[1] item=foo key=k name=myloop}
{assign var=op value=$smarty.foreach.myloop.index}
{assign var=cor value=$colors.$op}
{literal}
{name: '{/literal}{$k}:{$foo}{literal}',y: {/literal}{$foo}{literal}, color: '{/literal}{$cor}{literal}'}
{/literal}
{if $op le $count},{/if}
{/foreach} 
{literal}
]
```

**Please find the attached image for your reference**[image]

Comment: You can do it in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574609/php-html-decoding-help-converting-a-039quote039-is-bbold-b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is html entities, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp.

Instead of removing them you could replace them with their real symbol.

```
var Str = "Slogans such as McDonalds&#039;s";
Str = String(Str).replace(/&#039;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

If you want to strip them just change the code to

```
var Str = "Slogans such as McDonalds&#039;s";
Str = String(Str).replace(/&#039;/g, '').replace(/&quot;/g, '');
```

Here is a fiddle as a demo, http://jsfiddle.net/Zx9cn/

Comment: hey i want to use in smarty with jquery. when i use ant string functions its not affected with in {literal} {/literal} tag. can give me the solution

Comment: Please refine your question, smarty is in PHP and jQuery is on client side. The code above is valid in jQuery as it's pure javascript. Just transform your strings before creating the Highchart. If you have questions regarding smarty templates I suggest you tag your question accordingly! Here is the same example with jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/Zx9cn/1/