# htmlspecialchars_decode() function doesn't work

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

My PHP version is 5.6.

```
$str = 'how to use the &#039;Before and After&#039; model';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

Tried to echo the text with html special characters but the display is still showing the chars instead of the symbol. Tried `html_entity_decode()` as well but no difference.

The display from my website view.

[image]

Comment: I've tested on PHP versions 7.4 and 5.6 (same as you) and it worked fine for me in both versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP html decoding help - converting: A &#039;quote&#039; is <b>bold</b>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574609/php-html-decoding-help-converting-a-039quote039-is-bbold-b)

Comment: "My PHP version is 5.6" — **Extreme Danger** PHP 5.x is unsupported and hasn't had a security update in years. Use a supported version of PHP.

Comment: "the display is still showing the chars" — What display? A console? A browser? What exactly is it displaying? What do you expect it to display?

Comment: @UmairKhan I tried that and still doesn't work.

Comment: Working Example. https://www.tehplayground.com/Zx1DQj2dMrinbZOO

Comment: @UmairKhan I have tried using w3school try it yourself editor, exactly the same as my question and it works. it displays the symbol but it doesn't work when I tried to implement from my website.

Comment: Please check the html source.

Comment: @UmairKhan You are not being clear here. What should I check from the html source? Additional tag? Unclosed tag? or?

Comment: I wanted to ask you to check html source for `&#039;` as I think that its being sent as `&amp;#039;` in the output sent by server. Or its in `pre` tag which does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: I have checked it and the source is `&amp;#039;` and I used only `<p></p>` to display.

Comment: So this `&amp;` is the main problem, why your quotes are not properly shown. Your html source should be `'` or `&#039;` for quotes to properly display in html view.

Comment: @UmairKhan The user simply copy the text with special char `'` from google doc text and paste at my website then submit. So my system received the encoded special char. Is there a solution for this?